# How do I resize an image without stretching it?

Tags: c#, bitmap, system.drawing

I am trying to resize an image (bitmap) in C# without stretching the image.

Say the image is `100x100` pixels.

[image]

I am looking to make it `100x110` pixels, and leave a white gap at the bottom of the image where it added the extra pixels.

[image]

I have done this, but cannot find a way to specify the pixel format. I need it to be `8bppindexed`. I've attached an example to show the before and after image.

Here is the code I have so far.

```
string visit2 = "C:\\users\\moorez\\desktop\\visit2.bmp";

Bitmap orig = new Bitmap(visit2);
int width = orig.Width;
int height = orig.Height;
int newHeight = height + 2;
Bitmap newImage = orig.Clone(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
newImage.Save("C:\\users\\moorez\\desktop\\visit3.bmp");

Bitmap test = new Bitmap(width, newHeight);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(test);
g.DrawImage(newImage, new Point(0, 0));
test.Save("C:\\users\\moorez\\desktop\\visit4.bmp");
```

Comment: Please show your code. It is unclear what methods you use to create bitmap and how you draw another bitmap on it to help you.

Comment: GDI+ does not support drawing into an 8bpp image.  It is very non-trivial, reducing color depth from 16 million to 256 colors can leave a lot of unpleasant artifacts.  You'll need another graphics library, I think AForge can do it.  Best thing is to just not bother, 8bpp mattered two decades ago when 640 KB of memory was enough.

Comment: @HansPassant I would love to not use that format, but there is another program that will be run on the image that requires it. Thanks though, I'll look into AForge.

Comment: I wish SO users would document these "other programs".  So we know to stay clear from them.

Comment: @HansPassant I would if this were a side project, but this is for work and the program is not available to the public. Sorry.

Comment: Duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222711/image-resize-in-c-sharp-algorith-to-determine-resize-dimensions-height-and-wi

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(newImage.Width, newHeight);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
g.Clear(Color.White);
g.DrawImageUnscaled(newImage, 0, 0, newImage.Width, newHeight);
bmp.Save(@"C:\\users\\moorez\\desktop\\visit3.bmp", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: "I need it to be 8bppindexed"